# Push \texttt in tcolorbox to a new line if it doesn't fit

Tags: line-breaking, tcolorbox, typewriter

So I use a colorbox with \texttt for inline code fragments, and as you can see from the picture below, the code fragments run off the page. What I would like is for the colorbox to appear on the next line if it doesn't fit on the current one. The text is left-aligned, so that is the expected behavior for a long word.

The latex code is generated and manually entering newlines is not an option. Is there a way to tell LaTeX to put a newline before one of these colorboxes if it doesn't fit on the page? I'm open to suggestions.

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}               % code block backgrounds
\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}                 % align text left

%% Assign the texttt command inline code styling
\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
    \OldTexttt{%
        \colorbox{black}{%
            \color{white} #1%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
     bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \texttt{f9ad9eb95300413384ba3c3ef74159d2}
     
     asdh ahd kjah ksf jksh fjksdf jshdfj s hfjksf sjfh stjkhthf jksdfh sjkfh sjhfjkshf jshfjk shf sfjk shdfk hsjkfh sjkdhf jksd fjksdhf jkshf jkshdjfh sdh fksj fjksdhf jkshf jksh ks hf jsdf sjkfh sjdhf jksdhf shf sdhf jksfh sdjhf jksdhfjksdhfjks hfsdjf sdjkfh sdj fjksdhfsdh fsdjfh sdjfsdhf hskjf hsdjkf hsdjk hfjksdhf jksdhf jshf sdfh jkshf sjkdjfhjskdfh sjkfhsjkdfh sjkdfh sjdfh jsdhf jksdfhj kshdf hsdjfk sdkjf hsjkf
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Unless you use ragged right or left paragrafs, this is the normal behaviour for any `.tex` paragraf, being it inside or outside a `tcolorbox` (which you don't use in your code).